# Spark Java API: MapToPair & ReduceByKey vs. CombineByKey

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate, rdd

I have a Spark Java application, which builds a PairRDD like this

```
<key>, <value>:
01 , 1.2
01 , 2.3
01 , 3.0
...
02 , 0.0
02 , 1.1
02 , 12.2
...
```

where the key represents `day of month` and the value the `sum of sensor values`. However, I want to calculate the **average value per day**. Therefore I thought of the following two steps:

1. **Count** the amount of sensor values per day (= by key)
2. **Sum up** the sensor values per day (= by key)

The sum (2) is clear: Just call `reduceByKey` to aggregate the sensor values per day.

But: To count the amount of values per day, I have the two following options:

**A**: Use `mapToPair` & `reduceByKey` transactions like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Long> sensorValuesCount = sensorValuesDay.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String,Double>, String, Long>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<String, Long> call(Tuple2<String, Double> sensorValueDay) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2<String, Long> (sensorValueDay._1(), 1L);
    }
}).reduceByKey(new Function2<Long, Long, Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long call(Long countA, Long countB) throws Exception {
        return countA + countB;
    }
});
```

**B**: Use `combineByKey` transaction:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Long> sensorValuesCount = sensorValuesDay.combineByKey(new Function<Double, Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long call(Double arg0) throws Exception {
        return 1L;
    }
}, new Function2<Long, Double, Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long call(Long countYet, Double arg1) throws Exception {
        return countYet++;
    }
}, new Function2<Long, Long, Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long call(Long countA, Long countB) throws Exception {
        return countA + countB;
    }
});
```

Is there a difference in runtime or memory consumption? Which one should I prefer for such an "light-weight" task? And should I take another solution when calculating on "more complex" RDDs? Thank you!

Comment: Why not test both options?

Comment: For my small data amount (will get bigger over time) the two options seem to be equal (combineByKey took about 1 second less runtime (~2% in comparison with mapToPair & reduceByKey) difference, but a about 15mb more memory (~3 % in comparison). So my question is more a theoretical one, as I need to know how it would be in the future at a bigger data set.

Comment: If 1 second is a compromise that can be made, and you don't actually need the complexity `combineByKey` provides, I'd definitely go with A. As more data flows in, re-evaluate that decision and see if it still makes sense.